# Конструктор копирования

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

Почему не сработал конструктор копирования?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() {cerr << "Constructor" << endl;};
    A(const A &obj) {cerr << "Copy" << endl;};
    ~A() {cerr << "Destructor" << endl;};
};


int main (void)
{
    class A a, b;
    a = b;


    return 0;
}

Constructor
Constructor
Destructor
Destructor
```

Comment: потому что вы не копируете, а присваиваете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном коде конструктор копирования нигде не вызывается. `a = b;` вызывает сгенерированный компилятором `operator =(A const &)`. Конструтор копирования следует вызывать вот так:

```
A a{};
A b{a};
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас *присваивание*, а не *копирование*.

```
A b;
A a = b;
```

Попробуйте так.